# Multiple Checkbox Lists, item can only be selected in one list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a selection of categories.  I will have one or many textareas on a page.  Each textarea can be assigned to one or more of each category.  Each category can only be assigned to one textarea.

This is purely conceptual as this point, no code written yet.  I'm thinking each textarea would have a jQuery checkbox list.  The page starts out with a single textarea and it's related checkbox list.  All items in the list are selected.  User chooses to add another textarea (with a checkbox list).  All items in the second checkbox list are disabled, as they are already assigned to textarea 1.  As I uncheck items in the first list, they become enabled in the second list and can be checked.

Thoughts?  Good or bad UI?  How hard would this be to code?

Comment: If you want only one of several checkboxes in a group to be selectable, then you should be using radio buttons instead.

Comment: But they are two different lists, not the same list.  A radio button is not appropriate since I need to be able to select multiple categories from each list.

Comment: You'd have several radio button groups, each group spanning all lists, and each radio button in that group using the same label. The list name would be the `value`.

Comment: The coding difficulty would be minimal, but the UI sounds a tad confusing. What is it meant to represent, if you don't mind me asking? I would encourage you to stick with checkboxes, not radio buttons (not to directly contradict Blazemonger). Radio buttons imply a selection is REQUIRED, and would need to be scripted to become deselectable. Checkboxes would need the script still to grey out their counterparts, but they would be clearer.

Could you instead accomplish what you want with a selection list of text area names for each category? It's be fewer buttons, and no scripting.

Comment: It's for an ad purchase.  Kinda like Craigslist, you can select from many categories, but unlike it, you can put your ad under one or many categories.  So, typically, someone would pick say 8 categories out of a possible 300.  The tricky part comes in where the ad buyer can enter the same ad text for all 8 categories, or up to a different ad copy for each category.  They may have one blurb for the first 4 categories, another blurb for the next 2 and another for the last 2.  So from the master list of 300, they narrow down to 8 and then need to assign those 8 to one or many ads.  Clear as mud.